# certain number of choices in TKinter

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter, items

I made a checkbar in Tkinter with many items but I want the user can only choose the equal or less than a certain number of items. This is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Checkbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vars = []
        for pick in picks:
            var = IntVar()
            chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)
            chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
            self.vars.append(var)

    def state(self):
        return [var.get() for var in self.vars]


root = Tk()

lng = Checkbar(root, range(10))
lng.pack(side=TOP,  fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what should happen if the user tries to select more checkbuttons than allowed? Should another button be deselected? Should an error message pop up?

Comment: We will need to know the desired outcome in order to help. You can go several directions with this.

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry about that. I want the user can't choose any more after that. but if deselect some then can choose other buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbar needs attributes for the maximum and current number of buttons checked.  You then need a command that is called each time a checkbutton is clicked.  The command is called without arguments *after* the variable is changed.

If possible, code should be posted without dependency on as external file.  In this case, just pass a list of strings.  (I copied before Aran-Fey's edit.)

```
from tkinter import *

def checkmax(bar, var):
    # called after the intvar is changed
    def _check():
        print(bar.numpicks, var.get())
        if var.get():  # checked
            if bar.numpicks < bar.maxpicks:
                bar.numpicks += 1
            else:
                var.set(0)
        else:             # unchecked
            bar.numpicks -= 1
    return _check


class Checkbar(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], maxpicks=2, side=LEFT, anchor=W):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.maxpicks = maxpicks
      self.numpicks = 0
      self.vars = []
      for pick in picks:
         var = IntVar()
         chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var,
                           command=checkmax(self, var))
         chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
         self.vars.append(var)


   def state(self):
        return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   lng = Checkbar(root, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)

   lng.pack(side=TOP,  fill=BOTH)

   lng.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=2)

   def allstates():
      print( list(lng.state() ) )

   Button(root, text = 'Quit', command = root.quit).pack(side = RIGHT)
   Button(root, text = 'submit', command = allstates).pack(side = RIGHT)
   root.mainloop()
```

You should add a label as to the max number that can be checked.

Added note: When the Python IntVar is passed as the Checkbutton variable, it is replaced by a _tkinter.Tcl_Obj that does not have the .get and .set methods.  So the command needs a reference to the IntVar instance as chk['variable'].get does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by disabling all unchecked CheckButtons when the maximum number of CheckButtons is checked. Disabling the CheckButtons improves the user-friendlyness, because it gives the user a visual clue that no more buttons can be checked. If we didn't disable the CheckButtons, the user might be confused why nothing happens when he tries to click a CheckButton.

---

For the implementation of this feature, we have to connect a callback function to each CheckButton. The callback functions counts how many buttons are checked, and disables or enables the other buttons accordingly.

The first thing we have to do is to rewrite the `__init__` method. The `Checkbar` needs a new parameter how many Checkbuttons can be checked at the same time. We also have to connect the callback function to each CheckButton. I used [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to bind the checkbutton's variable to the callback function.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], maxselect=1, side=tk.LEFT,
                   anchor=tk.W):
    super().__init__(parent)

    self.maxselect = maxselect

    # store all variables and checkbuttons; the callback function
    # needs access to them
    self._vars = []
    self._checkbuttons = []

    for pick in picks:
        var = tk.IntVar()
        # bind the callback function to each checkbutton
        chk = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var,
                             command=partial(self._var_toggled, var))
        chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=tk.YES)

        self._vars.append(var)
        self._checkbuttons.append(chk)
```

Now all that's left is to implement the callback function. It simply needs to count how many checkbuttons are checked, and enable or disable them accordingly:

```
def _var_toggled(self, var):
    # count how many checkbuttons are checked
    num = sum(v.get() for v in self._vars)

    if num == self.maxselect:
        # if we're at maxselect, disable all unchecked checkbuttons
        for var, chk in zip(self._vars, self._checkbuttons):
            if not var.get():
                chk['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    else:
        # otherwise, re-enable all checkbuttons
        for chk in self._checkbuttons:
            chk['state'] = tk.NORMAL
```

(The `var` parameter comes from the `functools.partial` we used earlier.)

---

The complete code:

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk

class Checkbar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], maxselect=1, side=tk.LEFT,
                       anchor=tk.W):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.maxselect = maxselect

        # store all variables and checkbuttons; the callback function
        # needs access to them
        self._vars = []
        self._checkbuttons = []

        for pick in picks:
            var = tk.IntVar()
            # bind the callback function to each checkbutton
            chk = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var,
                                 command=partial(self._var_toggled, var))
            chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=tk.YES)

            self._vars.append(var)
            self._checkbuttons.append(chk)

    def _var_toggled(self, var):
        # count how many checkbuttons are checked
        num = sum(v.get() for v in self._vars)

        if num == self.maxselect:
            # if we're at maxselect, disable all unchecked checkbuttons
            for var, chk in zip(self._vars, self._checkbuttons):
                if not var.get():
                    chk['state'] = tk.DISABLED
        else:
            # otherwise, re-enable all checkbuttons
            for chk in self._checkbuttons:
                chk['state'] = tk.NORMAL
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a single list of lists.

I can assign the `Checkbutton()` and the corresponding `IntVar()` to a list inside of a list.

This will allow me to check each index for the IntVar() status and lock or unlock the checkbuttons accordingly.

Take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions.

```
from tkinter import *

class Checkbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.vars = []

        for pick in picks:
            var = IntVar()
            # appending self.vars with a list of 2 objects at each index.
            self.vars.append([Checkbutton(self, text=pick, command=self.check_count, variable = var), var])
            self.vars[pick][0].grid(row=0, column=pick)
            self.vars[pick][0].bind("<Configure>")

    # each time a Checkbutton is selected this method runs.
    def check_count(self):
        counter = 0
        # if the Checkbutton being looked at is check it will add a counter
        for cbtn in self.vars:
            if cbtn[1].get() == 1:
                counter += 1
        # if the counter reaches 3 then all Checkbuttons not selected will grey out.
        if counter == 3:
            for cbtn in self.vars:
                if cbtn[1].get() != 1:
                    cbtn[0].config(state="disabled")
        # if counter not 3 then all Checkbuttons are normal.
        else:
            for cbtn in self.vars:
                cbtn[0].config(state="normal")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Checkbar(root, range(10)).pack(fill=BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```